# How can I use an interface as an "out" parameter?

Tags: c#, out

```
public interface IAnimal
{
}

public interface IDog : IAnimal
{
}

public class Dog : IDog
{
    public bool has_two_legs = false;
}

public static class test
{
    public static void QueryAnimalProperties(out IAnimal animal_details)
    {
        //some sql queries
        animal_details.has_two_legs = true;
    }

    public static void Test()
    {
        Dog my_dog;
        test.QueryAnimalProperties(out my_dog);
    }
}
```

When I try to call the function passing and instance of the dog class with the "**out**" keyword I am receiving an error:

> "The best overload for method ... has some invalid arguments"

How am I able to pass a class which implements an interface to my database function to be filled with data?

UPDATE:

```
test.QueryAnimalProperties(out (IAnimal)my_dog);
```

Trying to type cast the input also gives an error:

> A ref or out argument must be an assignable variable

Comment: Your edit will work, but it's not doing anything useful.  Return the created object from your method.

Comment: i have now updated it

Comment: hi it seems to be working, rgds D

Comment: When you use the `ref` or `out` keyword, the compile-time type of the variable used in the call, must match the type of the method parameter exactly. It can be neither more specific nor less specific. That is because the method can both write new references to the variable, and copy the existing reference to other variables/expressions (although the latter is limited to occur *after* the first write in the case of `out`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an out parameter.

But if you want to use it, then use a Generic Method with constraints.

```
public interface IAnimal
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IDog : IAnimal
{

}

public void QueryAnimalProperties<T>(out T animal)
where T : IAnimal, new()
{
    animal = new T();
    animal.Name = "Fred";    
}    

public class Dog : IDog
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{
    Dog dog;
    QueryAnimalProperties(out dog);
    Console.WriteLine(dog.Name);
}
```

Note that if you remove the out parameter without modifying the rest of your code, then your application basically depends on what is known as side-effect, which is something you want to avoid in this situation.

http://codebetter.com/matthewpodwysocki/2008/04/30/side-effecting-functions-are-code-smells/

Comment: Thanks seems more complex than removing the out parameter, so i will just not use "out"

Comment: Generic methods aren't really complex...  But yes, there was no reason for the out parameter in the first place.  Oh and remember to return the object from the method after removing the out parameter.

Answer (score 3):

`QueryAnimalProperties` could return an object that is `IAnimal`, but not `IDog` (e.g. `ICat`). Such an object would not be assignable to an `IDog` variable. Therefore, this is forbidden.

Comment: @GrantWinney because it's an `out` parameter. Consider the direction of assignment: with `out` parameters in the OP's example you're going from narrower-to-wider (`IAnimal` to `Dog`) which is not valid, whereas with regular `in` parameters you're going from wider-to-narrower (`Dog` to `IAnimal`) which is valid.

Comment: @Dizzle you have a fundamental misunderstanding of typing in computer science and how assignment works when dealing with narrow-to-wide conversions.

Comment: I believe i dont need to use the "out" keyword and just input a object which implements the method properties defined in the interface it seems to work now.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to use the `out` parameter here.

Remove it from your method, and just update the properties of the class you pass to it (that are available in the `IAnimal` interface), if that's what you're intending to do.

```
public void QueryAnimalProperties(IAnimal animal_details)
{
   //some sql queries

   animal_details.SomeAvailableProperty = "SomeValue";
}
```

Because the class is already a reference type, when execution returns to whatever method called `QueryAnimalProperties`, your instance of `Dog` will retain the values you set in it.

Comment: I have tried it i get the following,
Use of unassigned local variable 'my_dog'

Assume i have to assign my_dog to a new object?

Answer (score 0):

You don't pass an instance of an object as an input value for an `out` parameter, the value will be discarded anyway.

Here's a simple counter-example that demonstrates why it doesn't work:

```
public void QueryAnimalProperties(out IAnimal animal_details)
{
   animal_details = new Hamster();
}
```

//

```
Dog dog;
QueryAnimalProperties(out dog);
```

In this case, the implementation of `QueryAnimalProperties` is valid because `Hamster : IAnimal` and `animal_details` can accept an object of type `Hamster` as it implements the interface.

But the caller of `QueryAnimalProperties` cannot expect `animal_details` to ultimately resolve as `Dog`, as my example shows, it might set it to `Hamster`.

As an aside, I don't think you're using `out` correctly: `out` means that the reference itself is changed, as though it were a pointer-to value in C and C++ (or as this is a heap object, it would be pointer-to-pointer value).

Consider `out` params as equivalent to the return-type of the function, change your function from this:

```
public void QueryAnimalProperties(out IAnimal animal_details)
```

to this:

```
public IAnimal QueryAnimalProperties()

Dog dog = QueryAnimalProperties(); // invalid, QueryAnimalProperties is not guaranteed to return Dog.
```

and it works the same way.

Comment: thanks for the comment but the return type in my implementation is actually used for another purpose.
in the sample i have used void for simplicity

Comment: I believe this is the correct way to do things without an out parameter.

Comment: @Dizzle I don't think you understand the concept of `out` parameters.

Comment: no perhaps i was misusing them in this situation, regards Dizzle

Answer (score 0):

This fails becuase `Dog` is a concrete class

```
   public static void Test()
    {
        Dog my_dog; // <-- here
        test.QueryAnimalProperties(out my_dog);
    }
```

The out variable `animal_details` in

```
public static void QueryAnimalProperties(out IAnimal animal_details)
```

just promises an `IAnimal` not necessarily a `Dog`

To fix this edit the type from `Dog` to `IAnimal` :

```
   public static void Test()
    {
        IAnimal my_dog; // <-- here
        test.QueryAnimalProperties(out my_dog);
    }
```

Comment: thanks i understand what you have written, i have got to the solution for this problem now.